# A collective word for finding community through sharing food

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, food

Looking for a word that would describe or better describe finding community amongst sharing food or finding community because of food shared.

Comment: Welcome to our site; I encourage you to take our [tour]. Please edit your question to include two things so that it can be reopened. First, please include a couple possible sentences illustrating how you would use this term, leaving a blank `________` where it would go. Second, please **present your research** into this by showing us which possible terms you discovered but discarded, and tell us why you found each of those inappropriate for your purposes.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! - Request for clarification: You want us to describe "finding". Does that mean you are looking for a verb? Or do you want a noun? Please state the part of speech that you want this word to have.  (Also show  us how you would use it in a sentence, with a blank where the word would go). Thanks

Comment: What precise situation are you referring to? Is this a host feeding a guest (a common courtesy in many countries to offer food to all visitors); sharing a meal with a stranger to make friends (sometimes called "breaking bread"); where a family eats together to foster shared feelings (a family meal or family dinner), or the situation where a nation has common food and common values and customs?

Comment: Look up the adjective _commensal_. It's Latin for 'eating together' and it's got a biological sense that enfolds the social sense. In fact, it's what E.O. Wilson says is one of the main requirements for true socialization.

Answer (score 1):

*[Break bread with](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/break-bread-with-someone)* is a phrase that fits the bill:

> The phrase *to break bread with someone* is to share a meaningful connection over a meal, often bringing together two people or groups who previously had reason to be disconnected.

(Etymologically, my mind goes also to [companion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/history-of-word-companion), though I don’t think that the Latin meaning of *pan* is well known enough for people to connect it to food.)